# Automating ftp processes

Tags: linux, ksh

My shell: `bin/ksh`

My system:

```
Linux 2.6.18-406.el5 #1 SMP Fri May 1 10:37:57 EDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My script:

```
ftp -divn XXX.XXX.XX0 << EOF!
user user pass
cd /home/dir1/dir2/dir3/
lcd /home/dir34/dir45
get filename
bye
EOF!
```

My issue:
I want to automate this process. I do not want to write all lines of code, what I would like is to write only the final directory "input" , the directory is "output" and the file name .

For example:
I want to send FILE1.txt from cd /home/dir1/dir2/dir3/dirdata to /home/dir34/dir45/dirfinal
I want to execute the script and only write in console:

```
dirdata
dirfinal
FILE1.txt
```

Comment: Have you looked into `expect` or just run `autoexpect ftp ...` and then type FTP commands in and then exit and then inspect the resulting script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
magic_script dirdata dirfinal file1.txt
$0 is the script_name (magic_script)
$1 first argument dirdata
$2 second argument dirfinal
$3 third argument file1.txt


ftp -divn XXX.XXX.XX0 << EOF!
user user pass
cd /home/dir1/dir2/dir3/"$1"
lcd/home/dir11/dir22/dir33/"$2"
get "$3"
bye
EOF!
```